# Mobile Website Platform Pros and Cons

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

I am in the process of converting a very large E-Commerce website into mobile website. I wanted to find out different options which can be used for this process. I am aware of different libraries in which jQuery Mobile seems like the most mature one.

I also glanced at Ionic but it is still in Beta. What are your thoughts on different libraries for implementing mobile websites?

Answer (score 0):

Last frameworks like Ionic+Angular, lavaca, famo.us... have better performance and faster than ever for develop, but they have still some compatibility problems with "old" smartphones (i.e. Android < 4.1), when jQueryMobile works better in old ones. Of course, as time passes this problem gets less important.

Take into account also that these frameworks are based on the SPA paradigm (Single Page Application) that possible is costly to adapt from your current website (JSP or JSF...).

If your app is based on J2EE JSF you can take also look into JSF-Primefaces that uses jQueryMobile as a front-end framework. Perhaps is a shorter path to reach your goal.